# Select date difference between two different rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database of hospital visits and appointment visits in the same table. There are three relevant columns:

1. PAT_KEY, which is the patient key
2. HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, which is the date a patient was discharged from the hospital
3. APPT_CHECKIN_DT, which is the date a patient came in for a follow-up appointment

The issue I am coming across is that even though the patient key connects the two, the HOSP_DISCHRG_DT and APPT_CHECKIN_DT are never in the same row. So, if a patient came in for a hospital visit, and then came in a week later for a follow-up appointment, they are categorized as different visits and are thus in different rows. (Thus, it's not as simple as doing a DATEDIFF)

My goal: 
I want to set up an indicator which is:

- 1 if the patient was seen for an appointment within 7 days of being discharged from the hospital visit.
- 0 if they were not seen for a follow-up appointment visit within 7 days.

Note: A patient who comes in at any time on the 7th day should be marked as a 1. For example, a patient who has a hospital visit on 2/6/2019 at 1AM who had a follow-up appt on 2/13/2019 at 3PM should be flagged as 1)

See below code for my attempt:

```
SELECT PAT_KEY, HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, APPT_CHECKIN_DT,

CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, cast (APPT_CHECKIN_DT as datetime), cast (HOSP_DISCHRG_DT as datetime)) <= 7 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS diff

FROM dbo.visit


WHERE HOSP_ADMIT_DT != 'NA' AND HOSP_DISCHRG_DT != 'NA'
AND 
PAT_KEY IN (SELECT PAT_KEY FROM dbo.visit WHERE DICT_ENC_TYPE_KEY = 108)


ORDER BY PAT_KEY;
```

I expected to see a table with the patent key and when they came in for a visit, with another column 'diff' which was either a 1 or 0, and showed whether they had come in a week earlier for a visit. What I actually got was a table of zeros, unfortunately.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a db<>fiddle would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sub query to get each row needed and datediff it to get the value you're looking for..